# Change a excel chart sourcedata with Macro

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to create a macro which will change the sourcedata of a line graph.

> The name of the graph is: **Tot_Failures**, name of the sheet which graph is displayed is: **Test_Results**, name of the sheet which the graph needs to pull information from is: **CycleNumFailures**

The code is:

```
Dim rangeText As String
rangeText = CStr("B1:B" & biggestCycleNum)

Dim chartSheet As Worksheet
Set chartSheet = Sheets("Test_Results")
chartSheet.ChartObjects("Tot_Failures").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("CycleNumFailures").Range(rangeText)
```

I have tried many variations of line 7 (which is where its failing).

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("CycleNumFailures").Range("B1:B" & biggestCycleNum)
```

and

```
chartSheet.ChartObjects("Tot_Failures").SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("CycleNumFailures").Range("B1:B" & biggestCycleNum)
```

the error message is:

*run-time error '2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'Range' of object' _worksheet' failed*

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Check the value of biggestCycleNum.

Comment: I have run it in debugger mode to check that string - It is perfectly correct

Answer (score 1):

instead of

chartSheet.ChartObjects("Tot_Failures").SetSourceData Source:=

try

chartSheet.ChartObjects("Tot_Failures").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=

This worked when I tried it on an example.